# Jquery ui tab. select all check box working only in one tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have created multiple tabs which contain one table each. Each row of the table has a checkbox and there is a check box on heading of each table which when checked selects all check-boxes in a particular table. Now this checkbox is working for first tab but when I switch tabs the other select all check-boxes are not working. All have the same id so I think one jQuery function would be enough. Below is the structure of tab and table inside it

Same happens with email button only first tab email works

```js
$('#all').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
  } else {
    $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> EN
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#tab-emp-name" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> EN
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">
    <div class="clearfix" style="margin: 10px 0;">
      <a href="https://mail.xxxx.com" class="btn btn-warning" id="email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Email
      </a>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <span class="label label-danger">Select All</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type='checkbox' name='check_all' id='all'>
          </th>
          <th></th>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>Date of Birth</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tbody-emps"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-emp-name">
    <div class="clearfix" style="margin: 10px 0;">
      <a href="https://mail.xxx.com" class="btn btn-warning" id="email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Email
      </a>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <span class="label label-danger">Select All</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type='checkbox' name='check_all' id='all'>
          </th>
          <th></th>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>Date of Birth</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tbody-emp-name"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a single equation ids!=unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ids must be unique, change it to a class or use a different selector

```
$('th input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);

    }
});
```

Comment: Okay so you mean if I have multiple id's. The jquery code will work only on one of them?

Comment: yes man you need unique ids or a selector based on a class/element

Comment: But there is again a problem. When  I switch tabs the state of checkboxes remains same ie lets say I checked two boxes in tab 1 and then switch to tab 2. Those two checkboxes that i checked are still checked in tab 2 whereas they shouldnt be. How do I fix it? So basically the select all checkbox is checking boxes of other tabs too. I dont want that

Comment: @Legendary_Hunter select the other tabs checkboxes relative to your current checkbox